# Launching jEdit From Java Swing App Using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jedit

I'm writing a Java Swing Application running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 server that I would like to launch jEdit to view log files.

Here is some example code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String cmd = "sh -c \"java -jar /tmp/jEdit/jedit.jar /tmp/test.txt\"";

    System.out.println(cmd);

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

}
```

The output is:

sh -c "java -jar /tmp/jEdit/jedit.jar /tmp/test.txt"

If I copy and paste the cmd output in a terminal window, it runs fine.

I have tried a bunch of cmd values, but I can never get the jEdit window to be visible.

With changes, this process works fine on Windows.

Is what I'm doing possible on Linux?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As jEdit is implemented in Java, perhaps it would be easier to check the source for what the `main` method (in the class declared in the manifest file included in the jedit.jar) does and do the same thing without using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` at all.

If you do want to stick with it, you could try passing the individual commands as an array to exec(), this often solved such problems for me.

Answer (score 1):

Linux uses the concept of display ports for its X-Windows system.  This allows it to maintain a different desktop environment for each user.  It also allows a user on remote machine to run a desktop app from the first machine but see the UI on the remote.

Windows, having only one available desktop environment at a time, does not.

First thing you definitely have to do is add the environment variable "DISPLAY=localhost:0" to the environment from which you are launching this.  However, you may also need to run 'xhost +localhost' or this may not be allowed.

Double-check, too, that you didn't successfully launch a bunch of jEdit processes that are now zombies (using top) and kill them if necessary (using kill).

Comment: If I can run xclock, does that seem to indicate that the display is setup correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exec()` needs some special attention. The exec method that accepts a `String` uses the space character as a delimiter to break up the string into commands. You need to use the exec method that accepts a `String[]`. Read more [here](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/java/online/io/javazine.html), specifically near the bottom.

Comment: I've tried that:

String[] cmd1 = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "java -jar", "/tmp/jEdit/jedit.jar", "/tmp/test.txt"};

Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);

// this does not open the jEdit Window

String[] cmd2 = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "java -jar", "/tmp/helloWorld.jar"};

Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd2);

// This prints Hello World to the screen.

I really think the issue is with the Display.

Comment: Did you try String[] cmd1 = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "java -jar /tmp/jEdit/jedit.jar"}?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve done this once and I got the same problem

What I've done is to write the command line into a text file and then execute the text file as a shell script file.
It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Jedit has a launcher script, `/usr/bin/jedit` I guess. Simply typing `jedit` in command prompt runs it, at least in current version, 4.5. Try that script instead of explicit `java` command.